# Gow to select unique id when ids are same and have different string values in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server. Now I have many same ids and the values of other variables associated with them may or may not be same.

I just want to select one unique id every time (I don't care about values of other variables). Values of other variables can be anything. I am just focused on selecting unique id and any values associated with any of the duplicate ids.

[image]

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: I am using SAS. in there I am using proc sql

Comment: I'm giving this one more try. There are different things that work in different versions of sql server. I see in the comments that you say nothing that people are suggesting "works" for you. I wonder if it doesn't work because you're using a version of sql server where it won't work, of if you just can't type. So what version of sql server is your SAS instance connecting to? 2000? 2005? 2008R2? Help us help you. Or don't.

Comment: I am using SAS Studio and under that I do all the data cleaning using proc sql and then go about writing sql statements. From what I researched, when it comes to TIES or row number, its a bit diffrent from sql and i am trying to investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `row_number` function to assign a unique number to every ID, and then query just one of them:

```
SELECT id, variablea, variableb
FROM   (SELECT id, variablea, variableb, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY varaiblea) AS rn
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks Mureinik. it is showing me error -                   
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY variablea) as rn
                                       ____
                                       22
                                       76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, 
              CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `WITH TIES` clause in concert with `Row_Number()`

Note: No Extra Field.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] int,[variableA] varchar(50),[variableB] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'xyz','abc')
,(1,'fgh','rty')
,(2,'qwe','ui')
,(3,'jk','vbn')
,(3,'asd','ty')
,(3,'fgh','po')

Select top 1 with ties * 
 From @YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order by variableA)
```

**Returns**

```
id  variableA   variableB
1   fgh         rty
2   qwe         ui
3   asd         ty
```

Comment: Thanks John, but this doesnt seem working.     
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  tableA
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order by variableA)